# gtest Death tests running first

Tags: c++, googletest

I was reading [Test cases with a name ending in "DeathTest" are run before all other tests.](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md)  .  Does that mean that if I have two test fixtures that both have death tests in them, that those death tests in both of those test fixtures will run before all the other tests in both of those test classes?

```
Clarification:
UtTestName.cpp:
TEST(Testname, Test1_DeathTest)
{
  //test things
}
TEST(Testname, Test2)
{
  //test things
}
UtTestNameOther.cpp:

TEST(Testname2, Test3_DeathTest)
{
  //test things
}
TEST(Testname2, Test4)
{
  //test things
}
```

Would the DeathTest cases in both of these cpp files run before Test2 and Test4 in the other cpp files?

Comment: Can you make your question clearer regarding the relevant cites from the documentation please? I think it's just ordering of testcase execution rather than how fixtures are handled in a specific order.

Comment: See clarification code above.  The link above has the line, "Test cases with a name ending in "DeathTest" are run before all other tests." and I'm trying to figure out what that specifically means, regarded what I added for clarification above.

Comment: The concrete cite from the gtest documentation is still missing.

Comment: I copied and pasted the line to search for in quotes there.